# ggplot2 geom_hex white border

Tags: r, ggplot2

If you look at the screen grab below you'll see that five rows of my `geom_hex` have a white border that make the plot look goofy. Why is this? How do I stop it? When I save with `ggsave` the problem gets worse (more white lines)!

```
library(tidyverse) 
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + geom_hex(bins = 50)
ggsave("geom_hex.png")
```

[image: Picture1.png]

Comment: Are they still there when you save the image with `ggsave`?

Comment: It only seems to occur at high values of `bins`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `geom_hex` only fills the hexagons and not their contours. Add a contour line (a "colour" in ggplot-speak) coloured with the same colour scale and that will fill the voids :

```
library(tidyverse) 
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_hex(aes(colour = ..count..), bins = 50)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: and it's also claimed updating to ggplot2 3.0.0+ solves the issue